# How to give validation for input field using angular2 in primeng

Tags: angular, primeng

i have a input field, i need to give validation for the input field. It must take only alphabets. no spaces are allowed, no numbers and no special characters should be allowed.Please help.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 pull-left m-b10 m-t10">
          <label class="col-sm-5 pull-left col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 text-sm-left no-padd">Name
            <span class="required">*</span>
          </label>
          <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd">
            <input type="text" formControlName="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" required pattern="^[A-Z\\a-z\\d-_\\s]+$" >
          </div>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
this.conditionForm = this._FB.group({
 name: ['', Validators.required],
      });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to change pattern like below,

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" required [pattern]="/^[A-Za-z]+$/" >
```

or you can also validate in your component like,

```
this.conditionForm = this._FB.group({
 name: ['',[ 
          Validators.required,
          Validators.pattern('/^[A-Za-z]+$/')
       ],
      });
```

you can also restrict input by doing like,

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name" maxlength="50" placeholder="Name" (input)="inputValidator($event)" required />
```

and create this method in your component

```
public inputValidator(event: any) {
    const pattern = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;   
    if (!pattern.test(event.target.value)) {
      event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
      }
  }
```